# How to fill out the Nav Log when reaching set heading point before the top of climb from the departure airport?

Tags: navigation, flight-planning

My current scenario is that I am flying from airport A to airport B. I need to reach 8000ft from sea level but it takes 22nm horizontally to reach that altitude and my first set heading point is 12nm away from my departure airport A. It is required that my set heading point is 12nm away from the departure airport A because that is where I will be changing track.

Do I split the climb into two or more portions/legs on the nav log along with a top of climb (TOC)?

Comment: Welcome to aviation stackexchange. Good first question :)

Comment: What requires that your "set heading point" be 12nm from departure?  Is this for a checkride?

Comment: No it is not for a checkride, but I need that set heading point because of mountains and other obstructions. Another reason is that I need to change direction when reaching the set heading point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule, or right/wrong way to complete a Navlog.

For a check ride you would want to be as thorough and complete as possible, doing it just the way you were taught, and probably including a top of climb as a waypoint to track climb vs cruise fuel.

(*although the [PHAK](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/18_phak_ch16.pdf) doesn't mention doing this...*)

However, if you aren't creating the log for anybody else but you, just do it in a way that you find most useful.

If you think calculating and displaying a waypoint line in the log corresponding to the top of climb would help in fuel planning or situational awareness, then by all means do it.

The Navlog is just a tool for you to use as you see fit.